# How can I access my android camera using an opencv python script on other network

Tags: android, python-3.x, opencv, networking, android-camera

I have tried the IP webcam software and it works with my code when my laptop and android phone is connected to the same network. But is there a way in which I can work with my laptop and phone connected to **different networks** or with them being separated by some distance as in my laptop/code runs in one city while my mobile that will be used to capture live images would be some other city.

Comment: this is not really a programming question. It's more kind of a network question.

If your phone is for example connected via WLAN to your internet box, then you had to enable port forwarding nad to determine your external IP address (e.g. by opening following url with a browser on your phone https://api.ipify.org/ )

Use then this IP address and the port that you used for forwarding to connect to our phone IP cam

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will check it but will it still work if both are not at all connected to each other by any means?